# Optimize aggregated query by retrieving last value in mongodb groups

Tags: mongodb

Good morning, everyone,

I'm working on MongoDB 3.4 and NodeJS. The query is taking about 8 seconds and I need to get this time down to a minimum.

My problem comes with grouping and using $$ROOT takes a long time. But I don't know how to do it without using this functionality.

This is my query: (First I look for an array, sort it, group it by date and then I have a JOIN with another collection)

```
Datagreenhouse.aggregate([
        { "$match": { "id_sensor_station_absolute": { "$in": array3 } } }, // "id_station": { "$in": id_station },
        { "$sort": { "recvTime": -1 } },
        {
            "$group": {
                "_id": "$id_sensor_station_absolute",
                "latest": { "$first": "$$ROOT" },
            }
        },
        {
            "$project": {
                "_id": 1,
                "id_station": "$latest.id_station",
                //"id_sensor_station_absolute": "$id_sensor_station_absolute",
                "attrName": "$latest.attrName",
                "attrValue": "$latest.attrValue",
                "recvTimeTs": "$latest.recvTimeTs",
                "recvTime": "$latest.recvTime",
                "id_sensor_station_absolute": "$latest.id_sensor_station_absolute"

            }
        },
        {
            "$lookup": {
                "from": "station_types",
                "localField": "id_station", // local field in measurements collection
                "foreignField": "id_station", //foreign field from sensors collection
                "as": "sensor"
            }
        },
        { "$unwind": "$sensor" },
        {
            "$addFields": {
                "sensor.attrName": "$attrName", // Add attrName to the sensors
                "sensor.attrValue": "$attrValue", // Add attrValue to the sensors
                "sensor.recvTimeTs": "$recvTimeTs",
                "sensor.recvTime": "$recvTime",
                "sensor.id_station": "$id_station",
                "sensor.id_sensor_station_absolute": "$id_sensor_station_absolute",
                "sensor.sensor_type": {
                    $filter: {
                        input: '$sensor.sensor_type',
                        as: 'shape',
                        cond: { $eq: ['$$shape.name', '$attrName'] },
                    }
                }
            }
        },

        {
            "$group": {
                "_id": "$id_sensor_station_absolute", // Group by time
                "medidas": { "$push": "$sensor" }, // Collect measurements
                "count": { "$sum": 1 } // Count measurements
            }
        },
        { "$sort": { "medidas.sensor_type.name_comun": 1, "medidas.marca": 1 } },

    ], (err, DatagreenhouseRecuperado) => {
        if (err) return res.status(500).send({ message: 'Error al realizar la peticion' + err })
        if (!DatagreenhouseRecuperado) return res.status(404).send({ message: 'Error el usuario no existe' })
        res.status(200).send({ DatagreenhouseRecuperado })
    })
```

How could I optimize this consultation?

Thank you very much.

**EDIT**

Using explain

```
{
   "stages":[
      {
         "$cursor":{
            "query":{
               "attrName":{
                  "$in":[
                     "2_191",
                     "var_TempInt_N7ARM",
                     "var_HumRInt_N7ARM",
                     "var_HR_Pasillo_N7ARM",
                     "var_RadiacionPARInt_N7ARM",
                     "var_RadiacionGlobalInt_N7ARM",
                     "var_CO2InvVaisala_N7ARM",
                     "var_Temp_Pasillo_N7ARM"
                  ]
               },
               "recvTime":{
                  "$gte":"2018-10-19T15:37:04.000Z",
                  "$lte":"2018-11-19T15:37:04.000Z"
               }
            },
            "sort":{
               "recvTime":-1
            },
            "queryPlanner":{
               "plannerVersion":1,
               "namespace":"iof2020.datagreenhouses",
               "indexFilterSet":false,
               "parsedQuery":{
                  "$and":[
                     {
                        "recvTime":{
                           "$lte":"2018-11-19T15:37:04.000Z"
                        }
                     },
                     {
                        "recvTime":{
                           "$gte":"2018-10-19T15:37:04.000Z"
                        }
                     },
                     {
                        "attrName":{
                           "$in":[
                              "2_191",
                              "var_CO2InvVaisala_N7ARM",
                              "var_HR_Pasillo_N7ARM",
                              "var_HumRInt_N7ARM",
                              "var_RadiacionGlobalInt_N7ARM",
                              "var_RadiacionPARInt_N7ARM",
                              "var_TempInt_N7ARM",
                              "var_Temp_Pasillo_N7ARM"
                           ]
                        }
                     }
                  ]
               },
               "winningPlan":{
                  "stage":"CACHED_PLAN",
                  "inputStage":{
                     "stage":"FETCH",
                     "inputStage":{
                        "stage":"SORT_MERGE",
                        "sortPattern":{
                           "recvTime":-1
                        },
                        "inputStages":[
                           {
                              "stage":"IXSCAN",
                              "keyPattern":{
                                 "attrName":1.0,
                                 "recvTime":1.0,
                                 "id_station":1.0
                              },
                              "indexName":"Indice Analytics attrName, recvTime, id_station",
                              "isMultiKey":false,
                              "multiKeyPaths":{
                                 "attrName":[

                                 ],
                                 "recvTime":[

                                 ],
                                 "id_station":[

                                 ]
                              },
                              "isUnique":false,
                              "isSparse":false,
                              "isPartial":false,
                              "indexVersion":2,
                              "direction":"backward",
                              "indexBounds":{
                                 "attrName":[
                                    "[\"var_Temp_Pasillo_N7ARM\", \"var_Temp_Pasillo_N7ARM\"]"
                                 ],
                                 "recvTime":[
                                    "[\"2018-11-19T15:37:04.000Z\", \"2018-10-19T15:37:04.000Z\"]"
                                 ],
                                 "id_station":[
                                    "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                                 ]
                              }
                           },
                           {
                              "stage":"IXSCAN",
                              "keyPattern":{
                                 "attrName":1.0,
                                 "recvTime":1.0,
                                 "id_station":1.0
                              },
                              "indexName":"Indice Analytics attrName, recvTime, id_station",
                              "isMultiKey":false,
                              "multiKeyPaths":{
                                 "attrName":[

                                 ],
                                 "recvTime":[

                                 ],
                                 "id_station":[

                                 ]
                              },
                              "isUnique":false,
                              "isSparse":false,
                              "isPartial":false,
                              "indexVersion":2,
                              "direction":"backward",
                              "indexBounds":{
                                 "attrName":[
                                    "[\"var_TempInt_N7ARM\", \"var_TempInt_N7ARM\"]"
                                 ],
                                 "recvTime":[
                                    "[\"2018-11-19T15:37:04.000Z\", \"2018-10-19T15:37:04.000Z\"]"
                                 ],
                                 "id_station":[
                                    "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                                 ]
                              }
                           },
                           {
                              "stage":"IXSCAN",
                              "keyPattern":{
                                 "attrName":1.0,
                                 "recvTime":1.0,
                                 "id_station":1.0
                              },
                              "indexName":"Indice Analytics attrName, recvTime, id_station",
                              "isMultiKey":false,
                              "multiKeyPaths":{
                                 "attrName":[

                                 ],
                                 "recvTime":[

                                 ],
                                 "id_station":[

                                 ]
                              },
                              "isUnique":false,
                              "isSparse":false,
                              "isPartial":false,
                              "indexVersion":2,
                              "direction":"backward",
                              "indexBounds":{
                                 "attrName":[
                                    "[\"var_RadiacionPARInt_N7ARM\", \"var_RadiacionPARInt_N7ARM\"]"
                                 ],
                                 "recvTime":[
                                    "[\"2018-11-19T15:37:04.000Z\", \"2018-10-19T15:37:04.000Z\"]"
                                 ],
                                 "id_station":[
                                    "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                                 ]
                              }
                           },
                           {
                              "stage":"IXSCAN",
                              "keyPattern":{
                                 "attrName":1.0,
                                 "recvTime":1.0,
                                 "id_station":1.0
                              },
                              "indexName":"Indice Analytics attrName, recvTime, id_station",
                              "isMultiKey":false,
                              "multiKeyPaths":{
                                 "attrName":[

                                 ],
                                 "recvTime":[

                                 ],
                                 "id_station":[

                                 ]
                              },
                              "isUnique":false,
                              "isSparse":false,
                              "isPartial":false,
                              "indexVersion":2,
                              "direction":"backward",
                              "indexBounds":{
                                 "attrName":[
                                    "[\"var_RadiacionGlobalInt_N7ARM\", \"var_RadiacionGlobalInt_N7ARM\"]"
                                 ],
                                 "recvTime":[
                                    "[\"2018-11-19T15:37:04.000Z\", \"2018-10-19T15:37:04.000Z\"]"
                                 ],
                                 "id_station":[
                                    "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                                 ]
                              }
                           },
                           {
                              "stage":"IXSCAN",
                              "keyPattern":{
                                 "attrName":1.0,
                                 "recvTime":1.0,
                                 "id_station":1.0
                              },
                              "indexName":"Indice Analytics attrName, recvTime, id_station",
                              "isMultiKey":false,
                              "multiKeyPaths":{
                                 "attrName":[

                                 ],
                                 "recvTime":[

                                 ],
                                 "id_station":[

                                 ]
                              },
                              "isUnique":false,
                              "isSparse":false,
                              "isPartial":false,
                              "indexVersion":2,
                              "direction":"backward",
                              "indexBounds":{
                                 "attrName":[
                                    "[\"var_HumRInt_N7ARM\", \"var_HumRInt_N7ARM\"]"
                                 ],
                                 "recvTime":[
                                    "[\"2018-11-19T15:37:04.000Z\", \"2018-10-19T15:37:04.000Z\"]"
                                 ],
                                 "id_station":[
                                    "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                                 ]
                              }
                           },
                           {
                              "stage":"IXSCAN",
                              "keyPattern":{
                                 "attrName":1.0,
                                 "recvTime":1.0,
                                 "id_station":1.0
                              },
                              "indexName":"Indice Analytics attrName, recvTime, id_station",
                              "isMultiKey":false,
                              "multiKeyPaths":{
                                 "attrName":[

                                 ],
                                 "recvTime":[

                                 ],
                                 "id_station":[

                                 ]
                              },
                              "isUnique":false,
                              "isSparse":false,
                              "isPartial":false,
                              "indexVersion":2,
                              "direction":"backward",
                              "indexBounds":{
                                 "attrName":[
                                    "[\"var_HR_Pasillo_N7ARM\", \"var_HR_Pasillo_N7ARM\"]"
                                 ],
                                 "recvTime":[
                                    "[\"2018-11-19T15:37:04.000Z\", \"2018-10-19T15:37:04.000Z\"]"
                                 ],
                                 "id_station":[
                                    "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                                 ]
                              }
                           },
                           {
                              "stage":"IXSCAN",
                              "keyPattern":{
                                 "attrName":1.0,
                                 "recvTime":1.0,
                                 "id_station":1.0
                              },
                              "indexName":"Indice Analytics attrName, recvTime, id_station",
                              "isMultiKey":false,
                              "multiKeyPaths":{
                                 "attrName":[

                                 ],
                                 "recvTime":[

                                 ],
                                 "id_station":[

                                 ]
                              },
                              "isUnique":false,
                              "isSparse":false,
                              "isPartial":false,
                              "indexVersion":2,
                              "direction":"backward",
                              "indexBounds":{
                                 "attrName":[
                                    "[\"var_CO2InvVaisala_N7ARM\", \"var_CO2InvVaisala_N7ARM\"]"
                                 ],
                                 "recvTime":[
                                    "[\"2018-11-19T15:37:04.000Z\", \"2018-10-19T15:37:04.000Z\"]"
                                 ],
                                 "id_station":[
                                    "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                                 ]
                              }
                           },
                           {
                              "stage":"IXSCAN",
                              "keyPattern":{
                                 "attrName":1.0,
                                 "recvTime":1.0,
                                 "id_station":1.0
                              },
                              "indexName":"Indice Analytics attrName, recvTime, id_station",
                              "isMultiKey":false,
                              "multiKeyPaths":{
                                 "attrName":[

                                 ],
                                 "recvTime":[

                                 ],
                                 "id_station":[

                                 ]
                              },
                              "isUnique":false,
                              "isSparse":false,
                              "isPartial":false,
                              "indexVersion":2,
                              "direction":"backward",
                              "indexBounds":{
                                 "attrName":[
                                    "[\"2_191\", \"2_191\"]"
                                 ],
                                 "recvTime":[
                                    "[\"2018-11-19T15:37:04.000Z\", \"2018-10-19T15:37:04.000Z\"]"
                                 ],
                                 "id_station":[
                                    "[MaxKey, MinKey]"
                                 ]
                              }
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  }
               },
               "rejectedPlans":[

               ]
            }
         }
      },
      {
         "$group":{
            "_id":"$id_sensor_station_absolute",
            "latest":{
               "$first":"$$ROOT"
            }
         }
      },
      {
         "$project":{
            "_id":true,
            "id_station":"$latest.id_station",
            "attrName":"$latest.attrName",
            "attrValue":"$latest.attrValue",
            "recvTimeTs":"$latest.recvTimeTs",
            "recvTime":"$latest.recvTime",
            "id_sensor_station_absolute":"$latest.id_sensor_station_absolute"
         }
      },
      {
         "$lookup":{
            "from":"station_types",
            "as":"sensor",
            "localField":"id_station",
            "foreignField":"id_station",
            "unwinding":{
               "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays":false
            }
         }
      },
      {
         "$addFields":{
            "sensor":{
               "attrName":"$attrName",
               "attrValue":"$attrValue",
               "recvTimeTs":"$recvTimeTs",
               "recvTime":"$recvTime",
               "id_station":"$id_station",
               "id_sensor_station_absolute":"$id_sensor_station_absolute",
               "sensor_type":{
                  "$filter":{
                     "input":"$sensor.sensor_type",
                     "as":"shape",
                     "cond":{
                        "$eq":[
                           "$$shape.name",
                           "$attrName"
                        ]
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      },
      {
         "$group":{
            "_id":"$id_sensor_station_absolute",
            "medidas":{
               "$push":"$sensor"
            },
            "count":{
               "$sum":{
                  "$const":1.0
               }
            }
         }
      },
      {
         "$sort":{
            "sortKey":{
               "medidas.sensor_type.name_comun":1,
               "medidas.marca":1
            }
         }
      }
   ],
   "ok":1.0
}
```

Comment: Please tell how many documents are there in the collection. Also, are there any indexes defined on the collection?

Comment: Hello,

the number of documents of the correction is : 22510726

and if you have an index by id_sensor_station_absolute .

Comment: Please run the `explain` with "executionStats" mode and update the post with the query plan output.

Comment: I added explain("executionStats") but when I use executionStats it doesn't show the seconds .

Comment: For MongoDB version 3.4 the verbosity mode "executionStats" is ignored for _aggregate_. That is the reason the stats are not seen in the query plan output.

Comment: one more problem...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207198/discussion-between-manolait-and-prasad).

Comment: As such the query is using index(es). Is there an index on the "recvTime" field? There is a sort operation on this field - and it looks like an index is used for the sort. Please include all details about the defined indexes - for proper study. Note that the $lookup and $group operations do not use indexes. Finally, note that the $match and $sort stages in the beginning of the pipeline can definitely take advantage of the indexes.

Comment: hello, there is an index in the recvTime field:

db.getCollection('datagreenhouses').ensureIndex({"recvTime":-1}, { name: "Index recvTime -1"})